# Using SUM with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum, case, mysql-error-1111

I'm trying to process the following query:

```
    SELECT TN.name_type_ne, WEEK(HC.date_check,1) AS date_week, YEAR(HC.date_check) AS date_year,
    SUM(IF(id_check > total_check_week, total_check_week, COUNT(id_check))) AS unique_check
    FROM HEALTH_CHECK HC
    LEFT JOIN TYPE_NE TN ON (HC.fk_id_type_ne = TN.id_type_ne AND HC.fk_id_ne IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN CATEGORY_NE CN ON (TN.fk_id_category_ne = CN.id_category_ne)
    WHERE CN.name_category_ne = "R4"
    GROUP BY TN.name_type_ne, date_week, date_year
```

It seems it throws an error for the next select :

```
SUM(IF(id_check > total_check_week, total_check_week, COUNT(id_check))) AS unique_check
```

I also tried to replace it with :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN id_check > total_check_week THEN total_check_week ELSE COUNT(id_check) END) AS unique_check
```

But I keep having this Mysql error :

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

What is wrong with the query??

Comment: Can you post the table structures, so I can create a mock query? Creating the schema on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be the best, and would go a long way for me to assist you.

Comment: SQLfiddle is limited me with " Request content too large (>8000) "
 Here's an inline link to [the DB](http://hpics.li/c5c3db6).

Comment: Try just dimming down the data a bit until it can fit.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. In my case, I was trying to use an aggregate function (COUNT) inside the SUM. It seems MySQL doesn't allow this practice.

Here is a solution with derived table:

```
 `SELECT SUM(unique_check) FROM
    (SELECT TN.name_type_ne, WEEK( HC.date_check, 1 ) AS date_week, YEAR( HC.date_check ) AS date_year,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(id_check) > total_check_week THEN total_check_week ELSE COUNT(id_check) END unique_check
    FROM HEALTH_CHECK HC
    LEFT JOIN TYPE_NE TN ON (HC.fk_id_type_ne = TN.id_type_ne AND HC.fk_id_ne IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN CATEGORY_NE CN ON (TN.fk_id_category_ne = CN.id_category_ne)
    WHERE CN.name_category_ne = "R4"
    GROUP BY TN.name_type_ne, date_week, date_year) As T`
```